# Primefaces Datatable gives null pointer exception when action triggered

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to use datatable component but using an array instead of an object inside selection property 
[Here is the sample from Primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf)

My domain name is **EfaDocLabelModel** and I updated the CarDataModel(from showcase) to **EfaDocLabelModel**  here is the code .

```
public EfaDocLabelModel() {
}
public EfaDocLabelModel(List<EfaDocLabelMatch> data) {
    super(data);
}
@Override
public EfaDocLabelMatch getRowData(String rowKey) {
      List<EfaDocLabelMatch> docLabelList = (List<EfaDocLabelMatch>) getWrappedData();
    for (EfaDocLabelMatch docLabel : docLabelList) {
        if (docLabel.getDoclabelId().toString().equals(rowKey)) {
            return docLabel;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
public Object getRowKey(EfaDocLabelMatch docLabel) {
    return docLabel.getDoclabelId();

}
```

When user triggered commandbutton inside footer part of **datatable** ,in my managed bean 
I try to get selected rows but it gives

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.reflect.Array.newArray(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:70)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decodeMultipleSelection(SelectionFeature.java:53)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decode(SelectionFeature.java:39)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:53)
```

I can run the multiple selection from showcase which used **CarDataModel** but using with the same structure when I modify it to according my need I gat this error.

Here is my bean

```
public class DocLabelBean implements Serializable {
private List<EfaDocLabelMatch> docLabelMatchList;
private EfaDocLabelMatch[] docLabelArray;


    public String updateLabel() {
    EfaDocLabelMatch[] selectedDocArray = getDocLabelArray();//I m sure I m 
    //getting error because selectedDocArray is null. 
    DTO result = new DTO();
    for (EfaDocLabelMatch docLabel : selectedDocArray) {
    }
```

Here is my page necessary code:

```
<p:dataTable emptyMessage="No Labeled Doc" 
 var="docLabel" value="#{docLabelBean.docLabelModel}" 
 selection="#{docLabelBean.docLabelArray}"> 
 <p:column selectionMode="multiple"  />
 <p:column headerText="Id" >  
 #{docLabel.doclabelId} 
 </p:column>  
 <p:column headerText="Doc No" >  
 #{docLabel.documentId}  
 </p:column>  
 <p:column headerText="Label Key" >  
 #{docLabel.docLabelKey}  
 </p:column>
```

And commanbutton code from page:

```
<p:commandButton value="Sil" icon="ui-icon-search"  
update="@form"  process="@form"
action="#{docLabelBean.updateLabel()}" />
```

I tried ajax=false and other possible error reason mentioned by balusc but still  I couldn't resolve the problem 
Here is 
[Bug report](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=2672) .I need to assign selected rows to an list or array if its a real bug is there any alternative ways ?

Comment: Can you please add your column definition.

Comment: @TooR thanks for comment I edited and added my columns.

Comment: How have you resolved this problem ?